# How do I turn an URL from firebase storage to the actual image in the excel worksheet?

Tags: node.js, angular, base64, firebase-storage, exceljs

I'm using ExcelJS to make an excel file from an Angular project and I already succeded in reporting the URL that it's in the firebase storage to the Photos column of the excel file (to be more clear, in the photos column, each row has the right url from the incident that the user is filing).
But I need the URL to be the actual image (the first one of the array), how do I do that?

I saw that there are a few things on the internet that say to use buffer or base64, but I'm not sure how to do that with a url from firebase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.